# Reapp default app not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to develop a hybrid mobile app using Reapp but I'm stuck at the first step. I installed reapp and created a new app. After running it for the first time it threw a 404 localhost:3011/main.js error. So I installed the dependencies:

npm install --save react@0.13.2

npm install --save reapp-ui@0.12.54

npm install --save reapp-kit@1.2.15

npm install --save react react-dom

npm install webpack

npm install webpack-dev-server

npm install minimatch-all

npm install --save react-router

After doing this, the main.js error was resolved. But now it's logging the following error:

> warning.js:45 Warning: Constructor(...): React component classes must
>   extend React.Component. Uncaught Invariant Violation:
>   Constructor.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may
>   have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
>
> ./app/app.js Critical dependencies: 7:22-29 require function is used
>   in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted  @
>   ./app/app.js 7:22-29

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any reason you're using this and not react native?

Answer (score 0):

The error say your app is having multiple react.

When you are using reapp kit it will include react and react-ui package too.